# how send N request without waiting for response in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want to send N request to a url, Without waiting for response. and check how server behavior for that?
my first question is: do cypress wait for response in `cy.request()` and how can I stop that?

and next question is: how can I send N pooling request without waiting for response?

thanks for your attention

Comment: Are you trying to test the performance with Cypress? Cypress is not made for it.

Comment: i try to test behavior of server when user send multiple request, for example when user double click on button and send two request in same time.